# Showing a state of another thread in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a GUI and the GUI is starting another thread (Java). This thread is starting a class which is crawling many websites. Now I want to show in the GUI how many websites are crawled and how many are left.
I wonder what's the best solution for that.

First idea was to start a timer in the GUI and periodically ask the crawler how many is left. But I guess this is quite dirty...

Then one could pass the GUI to the crawler and it is calling a GUI method every time the count of ready websites changes. But I don't think that's much better?

What is the best way to do something like that?

Comment: Only the GUI thread is allowed to call GUI methods. You cannot pass it to another thread.

Comment: @ErikEkman Well, technically you can, but then it gets messy with lots of `invokeLater`s...better to use `SwingWorker` :P - There's also the question of responsibility - who is actually responsible for updating the UI - the answer you and I would come up with this GUI classes, the crawler is, a crawler, let it crawl :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Ask the crawler how much work it is done isn't a bad idea.  The benefit is you can actually control when an update occurs and can balance out the load.

The downside is that the information may go stale very quickly and you may never get accurate results, as by the time you've read the values, the crawler may have already changed them.

You could have the crawler provide a call back interface, which the GUI registers to and when the crawler updates it's states, calls back to the GUI.

The problem here is the UI may become swamped with results, causing to lag as it tries to keep up.  Equally, while the crawler is firing these notifications, it isn't doing it's work...

**(Assuming Swing)**

In either case, you need to make sure that any ideas you make to the UI are made from within the Event Dispatching Thread.  This means if you use the callback method, the updates coming back will come from the crawlers thread context.  You will need to resync these with the EDT.

In this case you could simply use a `SwingWorker` which provides mechanisms for syncing updates back to the EDT for you.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

register a callback function to your thread. when your data is dirty, invoke this callback function to notify GUI thread to update. don't forget to use synchronization.

Comment: Don't forget to ensure that all updates to the UI are executed within the context of the EDT if using Swing